# Playing multiple sound files at same time with Windows Forms Visual C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, audio, visual-c++

I am currently working on an Independent Study project as a high school class. My project is to create a virtual piano using Visual c++ with Windows Forms on Visual Studio 2017. I want this piano to be able to play multiple notes at once, overlapping one another regardless of when each is pressed. I've managed to create a simple working model that can play notes using the PlaySound() method with .wav files for the sound.

My problem is that I'm unsure as to how to go about creating the audio system for this program. I've heard that I need to build an audio engine or use a sound library, or both. I'm looking into FMOD, but I really don't have any real experience with audio programming like this. Are there any pointers, tips, or any advice at all that anybody can give me? I'd appreciate anything at all.

I am running a VC++ Windows Forms project on VS 2017, my OS is 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Use some sound library like: `FMOD`. https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/cutting-your-teeth-on-fmod-part-1-build-environment-initialization-and-playing-sounds/

Comment: Perhaps it's better to preload all piano notes into arrays and then design an algorithm to calculate the combined sound when multiple notes are played together. There's concerns of avoiding oversound and smoothing tails.